# How to keep Java sockets low-latency in a loop using Http persistent connection?

Tags: java, sockets, http

I'm using a program in java that is repeatedly downloading some data from an API. I need this data approx. every 1 sec and low-latency is important for my application! So I made something like this (pseudo-code):

```
while (true)
   1: download from API
   2: sleep from remainder of 1 sec
end
```

The average download time is 40-50ms. 
When I omit the sleeptime (step 2) I get an average download time of 6-8ms.

I've tried this in many different implementations: HttpUrlConnection, HttpClient (Java11) and Apache HttpClient, but the problems remains. So I made my own socket implementation but the problem persists. Is there a way to fix this?

I have tried TCP_NO_DELAY but without results.

My socket implementation:

```
try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, 80)) {
    OutputStream writer = socket.getOutputStream();                     
    InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();                       

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {                   
        //request headers
        String request = "GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1"    + "\r\n" 
                        + "Host: " + hostname           + "\r\n"
                        + "Connection: keep-alive"      + "\r\n"
                        + "\r\n";
        byte[] wb = request.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);        
        writer.write(wb);

        String statusLine       = readInputStatusLine(input);
        LinkedHashMap headers   = readInputHeaders(input);
        String body             = readBody(headers, input);

        //SLEEP FOR A WHILE (THIS CAUSES DELAYS!!??)
        Thread.sleep(1000);                                             
    }
    socket.close();                                                    
}
```

Comment: ["...However, these sleep times are not guaranteed to be precise, because they are limited by the facilities provided by the underlying OS...."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)

Comment: How are you measuring the download time? thread context switching costs a lot of time.

Comment: If the download time gets longer when you pause, and assuming you have accurate measurement of elapsed time, then I'd guess it's because the server side is responsible - maybe some cache is no longer warm.  In which case there's nothing you can do.  But if your required liveness is "once a second", why do you care whether the request is in flight for 5mS or 50mS?  You can still achieve 1Hz polling.

Comment: FWIW, your 'sleep(1000)' does not implement step 2 as described, sleep for **remainder** of 1 sec.  I assume the solution is obvious?

Comment: @another-dave. I was fearing a certain issue at the server-side might be involved. Do you know a way to test this is really the case?  Overloading the API is not the main problem (they have a ratelimit of 8/sec).

Comment: @Neijwiert. I'm measuring using System.out.currentTimeMillies() and inside the loop. So the totalTime is the sum of N iterations. Does the fact that the sleepTime is not accurate influence the download times? I don't see why this would be the case.

Comment: @another-dave Referring to your FWIW, I ommited that for clarity reasons. So yes that solution is trivial.

Comment: @another-dave. Low-latency is more important than accurate polling frequency for my specific application. This is because the data being downloaded is volatile.

Comment: @Mijosa if you include the sleep in the measurement, then yes.

Comment: @Neijwiert. I'm not, else the mean download time would be in the range of 1000ms.

Comment: @Mijosa You could've naively subtracted 1000 ms from your total result. It was just guess work since you didn't actual post the measurement code.

Answer (score 0):

Another-dave was right! This issue is being caused by some server-side, maybe caching, issue. I was able to test this and make a work-around by doing 2 subsequent polls and than sleep the thread. I simply throw away the first (slow) poll and only use the second (fast) poll. Managed to get a ~4x speed improvement. Thank you for the help. 
Pseudo-code:

```
while (true)
   1: Do GET and trow away
   2: Do GET and use
   3: sleep for remainder of 1 sec
 end
```

Code adjustment:

```
//SLEEP every second time
if (i % 2 == 0 ){
    totalTimeFast += dur;
    System.out.println(i + ": " + statusLine + ", body length = "
        + body.length() + ", dur=" + dur + " ms   FAST");
    Thread.sleep(Math.max(0, 1000-dur));   
} else {
    totalTimeSlow += dur;
    System.out.println(i + ": " + statusLine + ", body length = "
        + body.length() + ", dur=" + dur + " ms   SLOW");
}
```

And partial result of an N=100 test:

```
90: HTTP/1.1 200 OK, body length = 187136, dur=8 ms   FAST
91: HTTP/1.1 200 OK, body length = 186658, dur=51 ms   SLOW
92: HTTP/1.1 200 OK, body length = 186658, dur=34 ms   FAST
93: HTTP/1.1 200 OK, body length = 186461, dur=51 ms   SLOW
94: HTTP/1.1 200 OK, body length = 186461, dur=7 ms   FAST
95: HTTP/1.1 200 OK, body length = 186374, dur=42 ms   SLOW
96: HTTP/1.1 200 OK, body length = 186374, dur=7 ms   FAST
97: HTTP/1.1 200 OK, body length = 186612, dur=39 ms   SLOW
98: HTTP/1.1 200 OK, body length = 186612, dur=5 ms   FAST
99: HTTP/1.1 200 OK, body length = 186550, dur=36 ms   SLOW
100: HTTP/1.1 200 OK, body length = 186550, dur=13 ms   FAST
Got 100 results with a  totaltimeFast of 1541 ms and totalTimeSlow of 4503 ms
```